# how to match more range sliders style to store in a single element by id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, filter

Hi I'm working on a project where I have four range sliders
every slider change a single css property of the html element (in particular a single webkit filter to everything)

I have:
hue
blur
grayscale
invert

now:

when I use a single slider it's all ok
but when i leave the slider and I use another one it set only one parameter to the style, writing over the previous

here an example of the code

HTML: this is one of the sliders

```
<section id="filters" class="clearfix">
      <input type="range" data-default="0" value="0" min="0" max="360" step="1" id="hue-rotate" oninput="hueFunction(this.value)">
</section>
```

JS: these are the functions

```
//filters
//hue
function hueFunction(hueVal) {
  var setAs = hueVal + "deg";
  document.getElementById("html").setAttribute("style", "-webkit-filter:hue-rotate(" + setAs + ")");
}
//blur
function blurFunction(blurVal) {
  var setAs = blurVal + "px";
  document.getElementById("html").setAttribute("style", "-webkit-filter:blur(" + setAs + ")");
}
//grayscale
function grayscaleFunction(grayscaleVal) {
  var setAs = grayscaleVal + "%";
  document.getElementById("html").setAttribute("style", "-webkit-filter:grayscale(" + setAs + ")");
}
//invert
function invertFunction(invertVal) {
  var setAs = invertVal + "%";
  document.getElementById("html").setAttribute("style", "-webkit-filter:invert(" + setAs + ")");
}
```

I would like to use every sliders together

Comment: why dont you try something like this `document.getElementById("html").style.filter = "blur(.....)"`

Comment: I did a try this way

//hue
function hueFunction(hueVal) {
  var setAs = hueVal + "deg";
  document.getElementById("html").style.filter = "hue-rotate(" + setAs + ")";
}
//blur
function blurFunction(blurVal) {
  var setAs = blurVal + "px";
  document.getElementById("html").style.filter = "blur(" + setAs + ")";
}

but seems it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this.

```js
//filters
//hue
function hueFunction(hueVal) {
    apply_filter('hue-rotate', hueVal + 'deg');
}
//blur
function blurFunction(blurVal) {
    apply_filter('blur', blurVal + 'px');
}
//grayscale
function grayscaleFunction(grayscaleVal) {
    apply_filter('grayscale', grayscaleVal + '%');
}
//invert
function invertFunction(invertVal) {
    apply_filter('invert', invertVal + '%');
}
var apply_filter = function (fil, val) {
    var filter = document.getElementById('html').style.filter.trim().split(' ').filter(function (a) { return a.trim(); });
    var f = false;
    filter.forEach(function (v, i) {
        if (v.indexOf(fil) === 0) {
            filter[i] = fil + '(' + val + ')';
            f = true;
        }
    });
    if (f === false) filter.push(fil + '(' + val + ')');
    document.getElementById('html').style.filter = filter.join(' ');
};
```

```css
#filters > input {
  display: block;
}
#html {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<section id="filters" class="clearfix">
      <label for="hue-rotate">Hue</label>
      <input type="range" data-default="0" value="0" min="0" max="360" step="1" id="hue-rotate" oninput="hueFunction(this.value)">
      <label for="blur-rotate">Blur</label>
      <input type="range" data-default="0" value="0" min="0" max="360" step="1" id="blur-rotate" oninput="blurFunction(this.value)">
      <label for="gray-rotate">Grayscale</label>
      <input type="range" data-default="0" value="0" min="0" max="360" step="1" id="gray-rotate" oninput="grayscaleFunction(this.value)">
      <label for="invert-rotate">Invert</label>
      <input type="range" data-default="0" value="0" min="0" max="360" step="1" id="invert-rotate" oninput="invertFunction(this.value)">
</section>
<div id="html"></div>
```